# Redux action updates the state, but it then immediately reverses itself to null?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to pick a random object out of a collection, and update the state with it's values; it's all being done in redux. The problem that I'm running into is that I get my random object, but as soon as the action completes, the state goes back to null. Here's what I'm doing:

1) I created an action file with one function. As soon as the app's button is clicked, this action is triggered.

```
import { mapData } from '../../mapData';

export const getRandomMap = (mapPlayerCount) => dispatch => {
  // get a collection of 1v1, 2v2, 3v3, or 4v4 maps based on the map player count
  const maps = Object.values(mapData).filter(map =>
    map.players === mapPlayerCount
  );

  const min = 0;
  const max = maps.length;
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  dispatch({ type: 'GET_RANDOM_MAP', randomMap: maps[randomIndex] });
}
```

2) Dispatch takes me to the reducer file that updates the state.

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
  randomMap: null
};

const mapReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'GET_RANDOM_MAP': {
      return {
        ...state,
        randomMap: action.randomMap
      };
    };

    default: {
      return state;
    };
  };
};

export default mapReducer;
```

3) And this is the actual screen with the button, that triggers the action (truncated unrelated code)

```
import { getRandomMap } from '../redux/actions/map_actions';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class RandomMapPickerScreen extends Component {
  state = {
    ...
  }

  handleSelection = (selectedIndex) => {
    ...
  }

  handleRandomMapRequest = () => {
    switch (this.state.selectedIndex) {
      case 0: {
        // 2 player maps / 1v1
        this.props.getRandomMap(2);
        break;
      }
      case ...
    }
    console.log(this.props.randomMap)

    //this.setState({ showPropThumbnail: false })
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  randomMap: state.map.randomMap
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getRandomMap
})(RandomMapPickerScreen);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({...});
```

Let me walk you through what I see in the debugger:
1) I click the button, and it takes me to the action
[image]
[image]

2) The app goes through all the reducers, and correctly updates the state with the  new randomMap value
[image]

3) It then takes me back to the screen file, and I can clearly see randomMap with correct value
[image]

4) The dispatch is done in my actions file
[image]

5) The code takes me back to the main screen file, however this time, randomMap is at the default NULL value... Why is this happening? Shouldn't my randomMap keep the value? 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to view the contents of a prop immediately after the action has been dispatched?  If so, React hasn't had a chance to re-render the component yet, so the prop will still have the old value.

This is very similar conceptually to trying to view the contents of a state change right afterwards, like:

```
// assume it's previously {a : 1}
this.setState({a : 42});
console.log(this.state.a) // 1, not 42
```

Because `setState()` is normally async.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to update the UI based on the value. What would be the correct way to trigger a re-render?

Comment: The re-render _should_ be getting triggered by the dispatched action and resulting state change, it just hasn't happened yet when you try to check the props right after dispatching.

Comment: It started working all of a sudden. Very strange. Thank you for your help anyway.